# Firebase - keep data updated

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list called `places`.

Every place has a list called `events`.

Every event has a list called `times`.

```
interface Time {
  day: number;
  startAt: number; // in minutes, since start of day
  duration: number; // in minutes
}
```

Now I would like to get all of the events ordered by the closest to start, and for that, I want to do something like google places does, and keep `nextDate` (which is a timestamp) for each of the `events`.

The only way I can think of how to do it, is by having a cron job, every minute, that goes over all of the events (there are a lot), checks the next time (simple function: `Min(startOfTheWeek + (day*24*60 + startAt)*60*1000)` for every `time`)

Is there a better way to achieve such thing?
Is there a way to trigger a function only when `nextDate` is smaller than now? so it will only run when it actually needs to.

Comment: Add your current database structure